# Android Ksoap2 SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Server was unable to read request

Tags: android, ksoap2

i'm using eclipse to develop over android, i'm trying to connect to a .net webservice... when i'm calling a webmethod ,it is not able t fetch the data when checked in log cat it shows

```
**10-27 11:46:44.222: WARN/System.err(638): 02-22 12:41:08.008: W/System.err(860): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' 
  faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. 
  ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' 
  faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@413ecc90
```

Please help me out i am new to ksoap2 in Android.....

Comment: Looks like you have a String input parameter that you didn't fill in, and the server doesn't interpret it as an empty string but just as a null, which is illegal for your SOAP service.  Fix: set the string to something of length > 0.

Comment: Check out the parameter name in webmethod and android request.addProperty("parameter name", pXmlString) should match

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error comes when you have not provided the correct URL, Method Name or Soap Action of the  web service where you have hosted your web service. Other reason might be related to your hosting of webservice on tempuri, check it carefully will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the NameSpace, I was missing the "/" at the end of the namespace.